# if(isset) condition in Extbase-Query

Tags: php, extbase

I want to do an extbase query with multiple statements. My query looks like this at the moment:

```
public function findOneCar($carid, $carcolor) {
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    return $query
        ->matching(
            $query->logicalAnd(
                $query->equals('carid', $carid),
                $query->equals('farbe', $carcolor)
                )
        )
        ->execute();
}
```

Now i want parts of the query only to be made if the parameter for it is set. For example if a person does net set the parameter for color, the query should not look for it in the database, but only look for the parameters that are set.

Something like this isn`t working:

```
$query->logicalAnd(
                    {$query->equals('carid', $carid),
                    if($color)$query->equals('farbe', $carcolor)}
                    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already solved it myself like this:

```
public function findOneCar($carid, $carcolor) {
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $constraints = array();
    if ($carid !== "0") {
        $constraints[] = $query->equals('carid', $carid);
    }
    if ($carcolor !== NULL) {
        $constraints[] = $query->equals('farbe', $carcolor);
    }
    $query->matching($query->logicalAnd($constraints));
    return $query->execute();
}
```